# Making both bounds of integration zero

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across a question while evaluating the integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos{t}}{1+9\sin^2{t}}\, dt $$

If you substitute $u=3\sin{t}$, you get:

$$ \int_{0}^{0}\frac{1}{3+3u^2}\, du $$

Which evaluates to zero because(?) the bounds are both zero.

But then, can't you substitute any arbitrary expression to change both bounds to zero -- making the value zero? So in evaluating:

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx$$

We could substitute $u = x^2-x$ or some trigonometric expression to change both bounds to zero. Clearly there is a misstep here, but which part of this substitution is invalid?

Comment: The function may not be continuous.

Comment: The substitution should be **monotone**.

Comment: That's a bold statement.

Comment: I think that $ \int\frac{1}{1+u^2}\, dt $ should be your new integral.

Comment: Suppose that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and $u(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. Let us denote by $F(x)$ some function such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that $$\int^b_af(x)dx=F(b)-F(a).$$  The substitution rule (actually just the chain rule) tells us that the indefinite integral $$\int f(u(x))u'(x)dx=F(u(x))+C.$$ Putting these two facts together, we get that $$\int_a^b f(u(x))u'(x)dx=F(u(b))-F(u(a)).$$ Now when we compute $\int^{u(b)}_{u(a)}f(u)du=F(u(b))-f(u(a))$.  I do not see any dependence on $u$ being injective here.

Comment: @BabyDragon: Good point; I was reflexively involving change of variable theorems from higher dimensional integration (which provide sufficient, not necessary conditions). I will delete my earlier misleading comment and update my answer.

Comment: @BabyDragon: You should add this as an answer. (I think you may need stronger continuity/differentiability hypotheses, but all functions are smooth here.)

Comment: No one has yet attempted to address the concerns in the last paragraph (about $u=x^2-x$).

Comment: @SteveD: BabyDragon's remark addresses it implicitly.

Comment: And I added a relevant comment to the answer below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem. See the comment by @BabyDragon above.

Note that the integrand satisfies $f(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) = -f(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)$ over the range of integration, so the answer is zero.

Regarding the last remark, note that for sufficiently smooth $f,u$, we have
$$ \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(u(t))u'(t) dt$$

With $a=0$, $b=1$, $f(x) = x$, and $u(t) = t^2-t$, this will result in

$$\int_0^0x dx = \int_0^1 (t^2-t)(2t-1)dt = 0$$

In particular, note how the change of variables affects the integration bounds.

Comment: In your example, changing the bounds from zeroes to a numerical range preserves the value of the integral, but what if we change a range to zeroes (my original question)? i.e. given $\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx$ and $u = x^2-x$, we end up with $\int_{0}^{0}f(u)\,du \stackrel{?}{=} 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, In your first big equation don't you need $f'(x)$ on the LHS?

Comment: @Cantor: No, its a change of variables. See any change of variable formula, eg, Theorem 7.26  in Rudin, "Real and complex analysis" (in particular the special case at the end).

Comment: @jellyksong: The above formula is the change of variables formula. When you use a substitution as above, the '$u$' is what appears in the original integral, eg, above would be $\int_0^\pi f(u(t))u'(t) dt$ ($u(t) = 3 \sin t$ here) and the equivalent integral would be $\int_{u(0)}^{u(\pi)} f(x)dx$. So, to use the formula as you have it, the original formula would have to have the form $\int_0^1 g(u(t))u'(t) dt$  for some $g$ with the given $u$. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

An idea so that no substitution will be needed, based on $\displaystyle{\int\frac{f'}{1+f^2}=\arctan f}\;:$

$$\int\limits_0^\pi\frac{\cos t}{1+9\sin^2t}dt=\int\limits_0^\pi\frac{\cos t}{1+(3\sin t)^2}dt=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\int\limits_0^\pi\frac{(3\sin t)'dt}{1+(3\sin t)^2}=\left.\frac{1}{3}\arctan(3\sin t)\right|_0^\pi=\frac{1}{3}\left[\arctan 0-\arctan 0\right]=0$$